# datetime being saved is one second off in Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime-parsing

I'm updating some datetime fields on one of my models.  I parse a whole-minute time (like 12:30) using `DateTime.civil`, then assign it to the attribute.  When I save and pull the data back out of the database, though it is off by a second (or less) - it comes out as 12:29:59, which is displayed in my app as 12:29.

I tried applying a patch like this https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/717a2941e15b32d07cc456bb0d81742ecfc5b4a3#L0R175 because of this old ticket https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3693-patch-activerecord-timestamp-conversions-fail-for-some-cases, but to be honest it doesn't seem like the same issue (and it didn't help).

```
(rdb:725) m.starts_at
Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:20:00 EDT -04:00
(rdb:725) new_time
Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:20:00 -0400
(rdb:725) Match.find(m.id).starts_at
Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:19:59 EDT -04:00
(rdb:725) Match.find(m.id).starts_at.to_i
1372954799
(rdb:725) new_time.to_i
1372954799
(rdb:725) m.starts_at.to_i
1372954799
(rdb:725) m.starts_at + 1
Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:20:01 EDT -04:00
(rdb:725) (m.starts_at + 1).to_i
1372954800
```